# view animation doesn't work in dialog while call show for the 2nd time

Tags: android, animation, dialog

I just created a dialog, and there is an `ImageView` in it. When I call `show()` method, the animation works fine, but for the second time I call `show()`, the animation doesn`t work. Anyone knows why? (The dialog was only created once)

```
ImageView iv_loading = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_submitloading);
Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.loading_view_anim);
iv_loading.setAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: you want show the dialog once or more??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
iv_loading.startAnimation(animation);
```

and add following lines in animation xml-

```
 android:repeatMode="reverse"
 android:repeatCount="infinite"
```

Comment: i do add the tow lines. it seems that the animation will be removed once the dialog dismissed

Comment: did you try using startAnimation ?